# how do I keep checkboxs stay checked after refreshing the page?

Tags: html, checkbox, codepen

I am studying how to keep checkboxs stay checked after refreshing the page.
And I find [this](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/xVevNw) helps.
However, the code, does not work right at my server. When I refresh, checkboxs stayed unchecked.
I also use [this](https://c.runoob.com/front-end/61/) compiler. NOT GOOD.
[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnYfZ.png)

The code I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#checkbox-container{
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#checkbox-container div{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#checkbox-container button{
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: .5em .6em;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="checkbox-container">
  <div>
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
  </div>
</div>
</body>


</html>
<script>
    var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
    $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");
    
    $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
      $checkboxes.each(function(){
        checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
      });
      
      localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
    });
    
    // On page load
    $.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
      $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    });
</script>
```

It seems to me that the code only works on CODEPEN.
May somebody tells me what is wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #checkbox-container {
        margin: 10px 5px;
      }

      #checkbox-container div {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }

      #checkbox-container button {
        margin-top: 5px;
      }

      input[type="text"] {
        padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="checkbox-container">
      <div>
        <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option1" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option3" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var checkboxValues =
            JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkboxValues")) || {},
          $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

        $checkboxes.on("change", function () {
          $checkboxes.each(function () {
            checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
          });

          localStorage.setItem(
            "checkboxValues",
            JSON.stringify(checkboxValues)
          );
        });

        // On page load
        $.each(checkboxValues, function (key, value) {
          $("#" + key).prop("checked", value);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code you provided has a couple of issues:

1. The script tag is placed outside the HTML body. Move the script tag inside the body or wrap the JavaScript code in a proper script block.
2. The jQuery library is not included in the code. To use jQuery functions like $(), you need to include the jQuery library before using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really works. Obviously there is a lot for me to learn.

Comment: May I go further and ask this: it seems that only for three checkboxes, it works fine. For four or more, it does not work--only the first three checkboxes can stay checked and the rest cannot.

Comment: What should I Do?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `fieldset` and track changes to the entire thing?

[image]

- No jQuery dependency
- Simplifies HTML
- Only adds one listener

I've also genericized the listener so that it can easily be modified to handle more fieldsets as well as other `input` types.  `input type="text"` support added as an example.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    restoreChanges("fieldset1");
    trackChanges("fieldset1");
});

// Reads localStorage back into fieldset's inputs 
function restoreChanges(fieldsetId) {
    var json = localStorage.getItem(fieldsetId);
    if(json) {
        JSON.parse(json).forEach(item => {
            if(typeof item.value == "boolean") {
                // Handle checkbox
                document.getElementById(item.id).checked = item.value;
            } else {
                document.getElementById(item.id).value = item.value;
            }
        });
    }
}

// Automatically saves fieldset's inputs to localStorage
function trackChanges(fieldsetId) {
    // Add listener to entire fieldset
    document.getElementById(fieldsetId).addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        var inputValues = [];
        var inputs = event.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName("input");
        Array.from(inputs).forEach(element => inputValues.push(
            {
                type: "input",
                id: element.id,
                value: element.type == "checkbox" ? element.checked : element.value
            }
        ));
        localStorage.setItem(event.currentTarget.id, JSON.stringify(inputValues));
        console.debug(inputValues);
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <fieldset id="fieldset1">
        <legend>Choose your options</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option1" />
        <label for="option1">Option 1</label><br/>

        <input type="checkbox" id="option2" />
        <label for="option2">Option 2</label><br/>

        <input type="checkbox" id="option3" />
        <label for="option3">Option 3</label><br/>

        <label for="option4">Option 4</label>
        <input type="text" id="option4" /><br/>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```